# Select contiguous data for a chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select contiguous data to input in a chart via vba. The data changes depending on the years the user wishes to see so can extend as far or as little to the right. The third line below shows where I try to select the relevant range but this comes back with an error message. I have included the rest of the code in case I have done the same thing wrong on the final line.

```
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.Range("F36", ActiveSheet.Range("F36").End(xlToRight)).Select, PlotBy:=xlRows
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Parameter Forecasts"
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.HasLegend = False
ActiveChart.Parent.Height = Range("E10:E34").Height
ActiveChart.Parent.Width = Range("E10:Y10").Width
ActiveChart.Parent.Top = Range("E10").Top
ActiveChart.Parent.Left = Range("E10").Left
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "=Parameter Forecasts!E37"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Year"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("F37",  ActiveSheet.Range("F37").End(xlToRight)).Select
```

Many thanks in advance,
Max

Comment: Shai's answer is good but, in case you were wondering what your actual error was, I think you might have just needed to get rid of the `.Select` keywords in the offending lines :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier and safer to define a `Chart` type variable/object, and set your chart to it. Afterwards, you can use the `With` statement to modify all it's properties.

It's better if you stay away from `ActiveChart`, `ActiveSheet`, and instead use referenced objects.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoChart()

Dim MyCht As Chart
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
Dim ShtName As String

Set MyCht = Charts.Add
Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")  '<-- I suggest not tuse ActiveSheet , but the Sheet's name, like Worksheets("Sheet1")
ShtName = Sht1.Name '<-- this is where you will put your chart later

' not sure is the string below representes the worksheet's name you want to put your chart
'ShtName = "Parameter Forecasts"

With MyCht
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .SetSourceData Sht1.Range("F36", Sht1.Range("F36").End(xlToRight))
    .PlotBy = xlRows
    .Location where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShtName

    ' you can keep going setting the rest of your parameters

End With

End Sub
```

**Edit 1**: changed to `ChartObject` to help PO with some extra help

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoChart()

Dim MyChtObj As ChartObject
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
Dim ShtName As String

Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Parameter Forecasts")  '<-- I suggest not tuse ActiveSheet , but the Sheet's name, like Worksheets("Sheet1")
ShtName = Sht1.Name '<-- this is where you will put your chart later

Set MyChtObj = Sht1.ChartObjects.Add(100, 100, 500, 500)

With MyChtObj
    With .Chart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered  ' xlLineMarkers
        .SetSourceData Sht1.Range("F36", Sht1.Range("F36").End(xlToRight))
        .PlotBy = xlRows
        ' the line below is not need since using the ChartObject
        '.Location where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShtName

        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = Sht1.Range("E37").Value
    End With

    ' set position marker for the chart object to Cell A1
    .Top = Sht1.Range("A1").Top
    .Left = Sht1.Range("A1").Left

    ' resize Chart Object
    .Width = 1000
    .Height = 1000

    With .Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
        .ApplyDataLabels  ' add data lables
    End With        

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The above code works fine, however when I try to add code such as the following: 
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "=Parameter Forecasts!E37"
I get an automation error, how can I avoid this please?

Comment: the code works great and places the chart in the worksheet. However it does create a new blank chart sheet, do you know any way to eradicate this please? Also how do you position the chart in a certain cell, and resize it. Finally how do you add data labels please?
Apologies for all the questions.

Comment: @MKaye LOL, I'm on my way home, i'll look at it tonite

Comment: @MKaye For positioning, try using `.top` and `.left`, for instance `MyChtObj.top = Range("A1").top` and similar for `.left`. Aside from that, you can find your answers in the MSDN documentation for a chart object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194426.aspx

Comment: @MKaye see updated code under **Edit 1** to include modifying position, re-size and adding data-labels

Comment: @ShaiRado, the code still produces a blank chart sheet that is unwanted, how does this get prevented please?

Comment: I am not getting any blanks, are you running only the code under **Edit 1** ? or both ?

Comment: @ShaiRado, I had a redundant line of code, all is cleared now, thank you so much for your help in all this

Comment: `.ChartTitle.Text = "='Parameter Forecasts'!E37"` note single quotes around sheet name containing a space.